# Extending a map of manifolds continuously

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds, and $A \subset M$ compact.  Let $f:A \rightarrow N$ be a continuous mapping.  Show there exists an open neighborhood $U$ containing $A$ and continuous extension $g:U \rightarrow N$ where $g|_A = f$.

Similarly, if $E(x)$, $x \in A$, is a continuous distribution on $A$ (distribution in the sense of differential geometry), show that we can extend the distribution to an open set $U$ containing $A$.

The latter question comes from studying a proof in Brin and Stuck's Introduction to Dynamical Systems (thm 5.3.1), where it is stated without proof.  The first is a simpler version of that question I made up.

Now it seems like the first question should be easy, just some proof involving partitions of unity, but I can't seem to find it.  There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of gluing together functions that's consistent with changing charts.  Also, a proof must use the fact that we're allowed an arbitrarily small neighborhood $U$ around $A$, since in general one cannot extend such a map $f$ to all of $M$.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What do you require about the map $ g $? Otherwise the answer to your question is trivial: it 's just $ f|_U $.

Comment: sorry, typo.  I meant to say $f:A \rightarrow N$, not $f:M \rightarrow N$.  Just made an edit

Answer (score 2):

Use Whitney embedding to place $N$ inside some $\mathbb{R}^N$ and then extend the map to all of $M$ with, say, Tietze extension.  The map can then leave $N$, but applying the tubular neighborhood theorem to $N$, we can continuously project the extended map back onto $N$ in an open neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer to the first question. Let $ A= K $. Let $ f(K) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} V_i $, where $ V_i \subset \subset U_i $ and $ \{U_i,\psi_i\} $ are local charts. Let $ K_i=f^{-1}(f(K) \cap \overline{V_i}) $. Then $ K_i $ is compact and $ \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} K_i = K $.

By Theorem 1 of pag 13 of Evans- Gariepy book we find a continous function $ \tilde{g_i} : M \rightarrow R^n $ such that

$$ \tilde{g_i}|_{K_i}=\psi_i \circ f $$

Note $ \tilde{g_i}(K_i) \subset \psi_i(U_i) $. Choose $ \tilde{W_i} $ such that $ \tilde{g_i}(K_i) \subset \tilde{W_i} \subset\subset \psi_i(U_i) $. Then $ K_i \subset \tilde{g_i}^{-1}( \tilde{W_i})= W_i $

Define $ g_i = \psi^{-1} \circ \tilde{g_i} $ on $ W_i $. Then $ g_i $ is continous on $ W_i $ and $ g_i|_{K_i}=f|_{K_i} $. In this way we obtain several local extensions of $ f $. But i don't see how i can patch toghter them for obtaining a unique  extension.

Comment: What does compact support mean when the codomain of $f$ is just another manifold?

Comment: you're right! My answer has to be modified. I 've made a stupid error in my mind.

Comment: sorry, made a typo.  the domain of f was meant to be A, not M.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm still not quite sure how $g$ is consistent with different charts.  In the summation formula you have for $g$, how are you adding $g_i$ that may come from different charts, or have you somehow prevented this from happening?  Sorry if I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: The last part of the proof doesn't work since the codomain is a smooth manifold and not just $ R $. Then muktiplications and sums don't have sense! I didn't think to this obvious and fundamental fact. I will try to modify it. Do you have some additional hypothesis on the codomain $ N $??

Comment: Do you require some 'algebraic structure' on $ N $?

Comment: Well, the first problem is just abstracting from the second one.  A continuous distribution on A can be thought of as a mapping from A to a manifold (I'm pretty sure, but haven't thought too deeply about it).  Regardless it seems like the first problem should be true, and seems interesting to know in its own right.  But if there's any extra algabraic structure that can't be added to N withouth messing things up, I'm not really sure, youd have to think more about what a distribution really is.

Comment: But along the lines of adding some algebraic structure to N, one possible solution could be embedding N into some $\mathbb{R}^K$ and then $f$ maps from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}^K$, in which case we can extend to all of $M$ and maybe project somehow the extension in some neighborhood of A back to $N$ nicely.  But I'm not sure if this is either more complicated than it needs to be or if it's even the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

See the paper by Bethuel and Demengel [Calc. Var. 3, 475-491 (1995)] which states, in the case M^n is a ball and A is the boundary of said ball, that the continuous extension holds if and only if \pi_{n-1}(N) = 0. The extension problem seems to have topological obstructions and relate to homotopy theory.